# Domain Objects Causing NHibernate Errors

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a domain object that has been auto generated for me by MyGeneration. This is generated using an NHbernate template. This is part of the object - I have removed most of it,

```
[Serializable]
public class Purchase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected int id;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public virtual int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set {if (value != this.id){id= value;NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");}}
    }
}
```

When I try to save one of these objects into the database I get an exception

NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException: The following types may not be used as proxies:
NHibernateDemo.DataLayer.Entities.Purchase: method add_PropertyChanged should be 'public/protected virtual'

Etc. So if I change this line

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

To this ...

```
public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

It works, but to me this doesn't seem like a great solution. NHibernate is treating that event property like it is a field it is going to persist into the database. Is there a way I can tell NHibernate to ignore it?

If I make it a 'virtual event' do you think WPF binding will still work with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception means that NHibernate can't create a dynamic proxy of the object because the event is not virtual. NH creates a proxy of your object to allow for lazy loading. Your solution is fine.

Comment: My solution is fine? So making it virtual will work fine with WPF binding is that what you are saying?

Comment: You need to make it virtual for NHibernate's lazy loading strategy to work. I expect that will work fine with WPF binding but I don't have any experience with it. The declarations have to be virtual so that NH can create a proxy for your object; databinding will work with the proxy as if it were the real object.

Comment: You say the solution is fine because it'll work, but to me this is silly.  NHibernate enforces that an event is virtual while it is actually not necessary since it doesn't contain any state.  
Next to that, it is a limitation as well:  what if the event is declared in a base-class and is not virtual there ?   Hiding and recreating the event in  your class will not work, since NHibernate keeps on throwing that exception.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels Is there a better solution? Sometimes you have to be pragmatic. Every framework I've ever used requires some compromise and you have to pick your battles.

Comment: There must be, since I'm facing the same problem and I can't make the event virtual. :)
I've read about a solution which lets you specify the proxy-interface in the class mapping and I'm going to try that (it means that my class will have to implement an interface and I suppose that by doing that, NHibernate will use that interface to generate the proxy).  I think that 'll be a clear solution (if it works). :)

Answer (score 0):

You must be explicitly mapping this property in your NHibernate mapping file. Take a look at the generated hbm.xml file and remove this property from the mapping file so NHibernate will ignore it.

Comment: Are you saying I must be mapping this field for this particular error to occur? That doesn't seem to be the case. In my mapping files there is no mapping to the PropertyChanged event